# How to detect zmq subscriber overflow?

Tags: zeromq, pyzmq

I am trying a architecture with multiple zmq publisher and a single zmq subscriber.

I want the subscriber to detect that its HWM queues are getting overloaded and spawn a new subscriber. This new subscriber will despawn when system load goes down.

How to detect system load/hwm queue status?

Comment: I am rather new to zmq, but to my understanding, the newly spawned subscriber will get copys of all publisher messages. So spawning a new subscriber will in fact increase te load as you are evaluating the published messages more than once. Maybe you want in fact use a push/pull scheme?
But unfortunatelly I have no answer to your main question.